# Error 404 Url Not Found when using InMemoryDbService in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-in-memory-web-api

I'm doing a web application in **Angular 8.3.21**. I'm trying to implemente a fake backend using **InMemoryDbService** to test my http requests. I'm also using `faker` to create random id's and words.

I have installed this:

```
npm install --save angular-in-memory-web-api
npm i faker --save
npm install @types/faker --save
```

My module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // A few components...
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule
    environment.production ? // "forFeature" because this is a module of a feature 
                                of my app which is loaded lazily
      [] : HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forFeature(
        AppointmentFakeBackendService
      ),
  ],
  providers: [
    AppointmentService,
    AppointmentFakeBackendService
  ]
})
```

The fake backend:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {InMemoryDbService} from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import * as faker from 'faker/locale/es';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AppointmentFakeBackendService implements InMemoryDbService {

  constructor() {
  }

  createDb(): {} | Observable<{}> | Promise<{}> {
    const administrations = [
      {id: faker.random.uuid(), administration: faker.commerce.department()},
    ];

    return {administrations};
  }
}
```

My service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AppointmentService {

  private url = 'api/administrations';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  getAdministrations(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url).pipe(
      tap(data => console.log(data))
    );
  }
}
```

Finally, in my component I call the method from the service to get the data:

```
constructor(
    private service: AppointmentService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAdministrations().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
```

Errors:

> GET http://localhost:4200/api/administrations 404 (Not Found)

What I'm missing? I have followed the official examples and I have tested solutions out there, but, didn't work for me.

I have changed this in the fake backend without success:

```
createDb(): {} | Observable<{}> | Promise<{}> {
    const data = [
      {id: faker.random.uuid(), administration: faker.commerce.department()},
    ];

    return {administrations: data}; // <== This line
  }
```

My goal is to create a fake backend, generating random information using faker and use a service to get the data in my component.

Comment: Same problem here with version 0.9.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the issue is with faker.

A few things you can try:
Add these functions to your `AppointmentFakeBackendService` put break points on the debug lines in the browser and see what you notice.
Key things to look out for is what collection it thinks you're trying to match to, and what collections are currently available.

```
responseInterceptor(resOptions: ResponseOptions, reqInfo: RequestInfo) {
   console.debug(resOptions);
   console.debug(reqInfo);
}

parseRequestUrl(url: string, requestInfoUtils: RequestInfoUtilities) {
   console.debug(url);
   console.debug(requestInfoUtils);
}
```

It maybe the collections are not being recognised, or that you have not specified a baseuri in your cofig:

```
    environment.production ? // "forFeature" because this is a module of a feature 
                            of my app which is loaded lazily
  [] : HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forFeature(
    AppointmentFakeBackendService, {
        apiBase: 'api'/
    }
  ),
```